# How can I get The Irregular at Magic High School's English-translated novel?

Tags: merchandise, the-irregular-at-magic-high-school

I have just finished the anime version of The Irregular at Magic High School and I would really like to read the light novel. I've been trying to find a legal way to do that but to no avail.

I've tried to search for the books in Amazon but typing "Irregular at Magic High School" into the search box didn't really give much (it only shows Volume 1 and Volume 2 of the light novel series but I think it has until Volume 17 now). A simple Google search only resulted in (I assume) unofficial (or illegal) translation of the original Japanese light novel series e.g. its Wikia page.

I am also having a hard time finding updates of translated materials for the light novel i.e. as in which volumes have been translated and which have not. MAL is the only source that I found useful for anime-related stuff, but it doesn't have much info on light novels.

To all masters of anime out there, is there an official site that allows newcomer like me to check about the official English translation updates of Japanese light novel series (especially the novel in this question)? Or is there a website out there that can direct me to the correct place to purchase the book? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yen Press has the license for the light novels](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-03-09/yen-press-licenses-irregular-at-magic-high-school-light-novels-manga/.85777). As of this moment, there are exactly zero volumes translated, but [volume 1](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/tsutomu-sato/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school-vol-1/9780316348805/?yen) is scheduled for April, and [volume 2](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/tsutomu-sato/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school-vol-2/9780316390293/?yen) is scheduled for August. I advise you to check their [New Releases](http://yenpress.com/new-releases/) page for future updates about when they release additional volumes.

There is not really an "official" site for this sort of thing in general, as far as I know. Your best bet is probably to identify the licensor for whichever series you're interested in (check [ANN](http://animenewsnetwork.com/), or just Google), and then look at the licensor's website.

(Yes, this is significantly behind Japan, which is actually at volume 19 as of March 2016. This is perfectly typical for English-language light novel translations. Compared to manga, there is relatively low demand for light novels, and they are relatively more labor-intensive to translate, so, honestly, you're lucky if you can even get a licensor to translate an entire series rather than stopping half-way through.)

Comment: All the links that you have given here are very useful. It's a pity that the English translations come so slow. I might need to resort to other means to quench my hunger for the story. Thanks!